# iOS 8 Swift - Do all attribute values need to be set to persist?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm playing with Core Data and I'm getting an exception when I hit save.

I have only implemented some of the attributes in the viewcontroller and I'm jusst testing it out with filling in one text field to see if it can be saved and rendered on tableview.

I wonder if Core Data requires all attributes of an entity to be set with some value as a rule?

This is my save function

```
 @IBAction func saveTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    // Reference to our app delegate
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    // Reference moc
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let recipe = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Recipe", inManagedObjectContext: context)


    // Create instance of data model and initialise
    var newRecipe = Recipe(entity: recipe!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

    // Map properties
    newRecipe.title = textFieldTitle.text

    // Save Form
    context.save(nil)

    // Navigate back to root vc
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

It breaks on newRecipe.title = textFieldTitle.text
And, this the error description and it looks like the title field is still nil

```
Printing description of newRecipe:
<MotherFood.Recipe: 0x7fd0e85e5b10> (entity: Recipe; id: 0x7fd0e85ada30 <x-coredata:///Recipe/t909A1383-DF1E-4FF0-83BD-DB95ADE9802A2> ; data: {
    duration = nil;
    id = nil;
    image = nil;
    measuredIngredients =     (
    );
    serving = nil;
    tip = nil;
    title = nil;
})
(lldb)
```

[image]

Comment: What exception is thrown when it "breaks"? Can you post the code for the `Recipe` class?

Comment: @CraigOtis See my edit with updated picture. It doesn't give me any message. It just breaks on that line and all I get is `lldb`

Comment: It looks like you have an active breakpoint on the line immediately above your comment. If you type 'c' (for Continue) into the debugger prompt and hit Return, does your code continue executing as expected?

Comment: Yes! it works, displays on table view as well. Do you know why this happens? Not sure what lldb is ..

Comment: `lldb` is a software debugger - an extremely useful tool for stepping through your code line-by-line to examine various aspects of your program. You placed a *breakpoint* indicated by the blue arrow, which tells the debugger to pause execution when it reaches that point. You can click the arrow to disable it. You can use the little icons at the top of the debugger to continue, step over/into/out of, etc.

Comment: I must have clicked on it by accident. If you like, you can create an answer with your consolidated comments for me to end this thread. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `lldb` has stopped on a breakpoint you created. (See the blue arrow on the line number bar, to the left of your code, directly above the comment.)

`lldb` is a software debugger - an extremely useful tool for stepping through your code line-by-line to examine various aspects of your program. You placed a breakpoint indicated by the blue arrow, which tells the debugger to pause execution when it reaches that point. You can click the arrow to disable it. You can use the little icons at the top of the debugger to continue, step over/into/out of, etc.